# untyped onGridReady method

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

The `onGridReady` method is untyped in the latest (v 28) `ag-grid-react` package. Meaning I can do the following:

```
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params) => {
     gridApi.current = params.api_this_is_not_the_real_name;
  }, [gridApi]);

  ...

  <AgGridReact
        ...
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        ...
      >
  </AgGridReact>
```

… and TypeScript will not complain. Grepping through the sources of the `ag-grid-communty` package under `node_modules` I found the definition for the `GridReadyEvent` which I suppose I can use  to strongly type the above callback. However, I failed to find the definition of this interface in the `@ag-grid-community/all-modules` or `@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` which is the supported way of importing AgGrid dependencies (as advised [in the official documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/react/building-typescript/)). The official documentation also [warns](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/javascript/modules/)  against mixing the `ag-grid-community` package and the `@ag-grid-community/all-modules` modules.

So my question is: what is the proper way to strongly type the `onGridReady` callback?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally did it. It turns out that the `onGridReady` method is not "untyped" as I erroneously stated. The `params` argument is actually a `GridReadyEvent`. However to achieve type safety you also need to supply the generic argument, otherwise `GridReadyEvent` is interpreted as `GridReadyEvent<any>` and type safety goes out of the window:

```
onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent<YourGridRowDataType>) => { ...
```